# Deleting a specific letter in an element with a length of at least one

Tags: python-3.x

Given the list:

```
lst = ["apples", "oranges", "pears"]
```

How can I delete the letter "e" in "apples" from the list so that the result will look something like this:

```
lst = ["appls", "oranges", "pears"]
```

Comment: please, try some code first and in case of any issue ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you just want to remove "e" from the first element of the list?

```
lst[0] = lst[0].replace("e", "")
```

Above code will replace every "e" with "" (blank) so it will remove every "e".

Comment: Yes, I want to remove "e" from the first element of the list.

Your solution worked nonetheless. Thanks a lot